# issue with vsftpd - no matter what I do, users can go up in the directory

Tags: permissions, directory, users, ftp, vsftpd

I've set up vsftp on an Ubuntu server.

Configuration is as follows:

```
listen=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
use_localtime=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
ftpd_banner=Welcome to proM FTP service.
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=NO
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list

secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd/empty
pam_service_name=vsftpd
rsa_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
rsa_private_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

Users can log in, they can upload files, but they also can change the directory and even go to `/` if they want.

I've tried everything:

- adding `allow_writeable_chroot=YES`
- creating users with `shell=/bin/false` - they can't even log in
- changing the permissions - then login also fails.

Nothing works. Any idea anyone?